Solve is not not working when I am using s as variable instead of x?
The following is  the code.
eqn1 = -Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s  ] + (
    Subscript[V, D1] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    n1]] + Subscript[V, D1]/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, p1]] + 
    s*Subscript[C, L1] Subscript[V, D1] == 0;
eqn2 = (Subscript[V, in] - Subscript[V, s])/Subscript[R, s] == 
   Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] Subscript[V, s] - (
    Subscript[V, s] - Subscript[V, D1])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, n1]];
Solve[eqn1 && eqn2, {Subscript[V, D1], Subscript[V, 
   s]}] // TraditionalForm
eq3 = Denominator[((-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] - 1/Subscript[r, 
       Subscript[o, n1]]) Subscript[V, 
     in])/(((-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] - 1/Subscript[r, 
        Subscript[o, n1]])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
       n1]] + (s Subscript[C, L1] + 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
          n1]] + 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
          p1]]) (-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] + 1/Subscript[r, 
          Subscript[o, n1]] - 1/Subscript[R, s])) Subscript[R, 
     s])] == 0;
Solve[eq3, s]

This will generate error
Solve::nsmet: This system cannot be solved with the methods available to Solve.

However, if I replace s with x. Solve  is working without throwing any error.
Solve[(-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] - 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
    n1]])/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
   n1]] + (x Subscript[C, L1] + 1/Subscript[r, Subscript[o, n1]] + 1/
      Subscript[r, Subscript[o, 
      p1]]) (-Subscript[g, Subscript[m, n1]] + 1/Subscript[r, 
      Subscript[o, n1]] - 1/Subscript[R, s]) == 0, x]


This is likely due to the subscript s in Subscript[R,s]. Mathematica treats the s as a variable, and it doesn't know how to get s out of the Subscript. It is generally recommended that Mathematica users avoid the use of Subscripts when solving equations, doing algebra, etc., exactly for weird things like this. Indeed, if you change Subscript[R, s] to Subscript[R, x] when solving for x, the second bit of code throws the same error.

Instead of using Subscript[a,b], in general it makes sense to use a[b] and define a Format value for a if you really need it to format in output with a subscript. Using Subscript when doing complex algebra or coding is asking for trouble.
